# MongoDB large one-time query load on production system

Tags: mongodb

I'm having a MongoDB database, holding tens of millions of documents.
Let's say I want to query a single value out of each document (see image below: `target` key under `0` key under `references` key)
so it's a 3rd level nested key, and only if the `referenceType` equals `"CopiedFrom"` (`references` level doesn't exists in all documents)
there's ~10M documents that will answer this condition, and this is a one-time query.

[image: Schema example]

The DBA in my org tells me this database is transactional (and not for reporting) and serves many clients in production, hence, a query like i'm asking will put great load on the system and will compromise production response times.

I don't have much experience with MongoDB and cannot evaluate this claim (besides the fact that it's absurd to have historical data you cannot effectivly access).
**Is he right, or he's exaggerating?**
knowing this can help me deal with his claim, and get the data i need.

thanks!

Comment: In general, using correct indexes and properly forming your query filter / projection can result in a query with good performance. Also, you can schedule your query when the load from clients is minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is addressed by adding dedicated hidden nodes to the replica set for analytics queries. See [here](https://blog.mlab.com/2016/10/configuring-a-mongodb-replica-set-for-analytics/) for example.

The DBA is generally correct in that an expensive analytical query is unsuitable for executing against servers that serve transactional workloads.

Comment: thanks! this is helpful. But i'm also asking is whether the query I described is actually expensive (as far as you can tell)? it is less of a sophisticated analytical query but more of a partial extract.

Comment: There is not enough information to comment on that. Review general query optimization documentation including how to read explain output.